# hibernate and dates

Tags: hibernate, timestamp, date

I want to get records between start date and end date using hibernate .Like,

```
id     startDate                 endDate
15     2011-01-05 05:05:10   2011-05-01 09:05:10 
37     2010-03-01 05:06:10   2010-06-01 09:07:10
49     2005-01-05 03:03:03   2005-05-01 08:08:08
```

I want to retrive 15 when provided startDate=2011-01-05 05:05:10 and endDate=2011-05-01 09:05:10

I want to retrive 37 when provided startDate=2010-03-01 05:06:10 and endDate=2010-06-01 09:07:10

Can anybody tell me  how to do using hibernate ? I tried using between clause but not worked .

Answer (score 0):

What Criteria did you try to use?  If both startDate and endDate need to match for the row to be returned, then you can try using the following Restrictions:

```
Restrictions.and(Restrictions.eq("startDate",startDateValue),Restrictions.eq("endDate", endDateValue))
```